# local sharelatex compile too slow

Tags: latex, sharelatex

I am running a sharelatex docker image (Docker version 1.13.1) on an ubuntu14.04 that installed in virtualbox(8 core, 16G memory). When I compile a project (scale of 4 pages of pdf), it was so slow that it takes more than ten times as that when I compile the same project on sharelatex.com, and I have tried to compile it using command line on the virtual machine, it was fast. And I have used command $top to monitor top processes, when I click compile button on the client side, after 2 or 3 minutes, the xelatex process showed up in a flash, right after the xelatex disappear the project was compiled.

I was wondering what was happening in those 2 or 3 minutes, has anybody else encountered this problem. Any suggestion is appreciated.